# How to attach attachmement in outlook email through vba from MS Access?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have programmed in access vba to send bulk email on different selections and it is done. Now the requirement is need to add attachments to email from document library to generated email.

Is there any way can we achieve this? Is it possible through Power Automate?

I have unique text in Subject line. I would appreciate any help. 
Thanks,

Mangesh

Answer (score 0):

I myself got the solution.

**I just sync the folder to my one drive and issue got resolved.**

Regards,

Mangesh